# Setting the scroll position in edit control

Tags: c, windows, winapi, controls, edit

I'm trying to set the scroll position in edit control and I want set it 20% to bottom from the top. how I may go do that by taking a percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WM_VSCROLL` message is sent to a window when a scroll event occurs in the window's standard vertical scroll bar. This message is also sent to the owner of a vertical scroll bar control when a scroll event occurs in the control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can first `GetScrollRange()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), calculate how many lines there are, then calculate the percentage. Afterward `WindowProc()` with `VM_SCROLL` or, of a much more simpler solution use the `SetScrollPos()` function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can find all the scroll functions here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486021%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea why vertical scroll moves when text is added into multiline edit control even when the AUTOSCROLL Flag is disabled?

Comment: The ES_AUTOHSCROLL style tells the edit control to scroll the text horizontally, when necessary, as the user enters text. If this style is not specified, the edit control cannot scroll horizontally. For single-line edit controls without ES_AUTOHSCROLL, only the characters that fill the visible area of the control are accepted. For multiline edit controls without ES_AUTOHSCROLL, the text wraps to the next line when the user enters more text than can be displayed on a single line...

Comment: ...If ES_AUTOHSCROLL is specified for a multiline edit control, the control scrolls horizontally when the user enters more text than can be displayed on a single line; the text will not wrap. ~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775456%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#edit_scroll_styles

Comment: Maybe you should try setting the range instead with `SetScrollRange()`

Comment: or `SetScrollPosition()` to a constant value (like your 20%) and have it set on every input character. Let me know if this is a solution.

Comment: Solved thanks! I calculated the RECT of lines in edit control and set the scroll on where position is (1/5 * Width).

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for an edit control setting the scroll position doesn't appear to actually move the text to the position expected. The scroll bar position is moved but the text stays where it is at.

To scroll an edit box I found the following to work as I expected:

```
double desiredPercentage = 0.7;
CEdit* pEditBox = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CONTROLID)

int totalLines = pEditLog->GetLineCount();
// Truncatest to the nearest int, do different rounding method for round up/down.
int scrollLine = (int)(desiredPercentage * (double)totalLines));

pEditBox->LineScroll(scrollLine);
```